# Eclipse SVEditor plugin not finding path

Tags: eclipse, plugins, verilog, system-verilog

I'm new to Verilog, so I apologize for my question doesn't make sense, but I've been trying to set up an eclipse plug-in called SVEditor, and I'm getting this error in the output: `[SVDBArgFileParser] Argument file "${workspace_loc}/chip1/sim/files.f" ("${workspace_loc}/chip1/sim") does not exist`

Here is the tutorial I was following: http://sveditor.sourceforge.net/tutorial/sveditor_tutorial.html

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
 ${workspace_loc:/chip1/sim/files.f}
```

which works in contrast to `${workspace_loc}/chip1/sim/files.f` also when e. g. the project folder `chip1` is not a subfolder of the workspace directory, but linked to a different location (which e. g. is usually the case when you use Git).